# How to access nested template attributes?

Tags: meteor, quill

I successfully implemented a form with quill wysiwyg but now I want to create a component to reuse it. This is my working implementation:

```html
<template name="form">
  <form>
    <div id="toolbar"> ... html with toolbar buttons </div>
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="save"/>
  </form>
</template>
```

```js
Template.form.rendered = function () {
  this.quill = new Quill('#editor', { 
    modules: {
     'toolbar': { container: '#toolbar' },
     'link-tooltip': true
    },
    theme: 'snow' }
  );
}

Template.form.events({
  'submit form': function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var html = tmpl.quill.getHTML();
    // code to save the form data
}
```

This is what I want to make it reusable. My questions are inside the code:

```html
<template name="form">
  <form>
    {{> editor }}
    <input type="submit" value="save"/>
  </form>
</template>

<template name="editor">
  <div id="toolbar"> ... html with toolbar buttons </div>
  <div id="editor"></div>
</template>
```

```js
Template.editor.rendered = function () {
  this.quill = new Quill('#editor', { 
    modules: {
     'toolbar': { container: '#toolbar' },
     'link-tooltip': true
    },
    theme: 'snow' }
  );

  // How can I pass quill to the parent template?

}

Template.form.events({
  'submit form': function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // How can I access quill variable on the nested template, so I can 
    // call quill.getHTML()?

}
```

Comment: [autoform](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform) will save you a lot of trouble. `{{> quickForm collection="Books" doc=editingDoc id="updateBookForm" type="update"}}`

Comment: Dan, autoform look great, but I can't see how that package solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pattern I use to solve this sort of problem. Define a class called `Editor` and a template `editor`. The intention is that the data context inside `editor` will be an instance of `Editor`.

```js
function Editor() {
  this.quill = null;
}

Template.editor.rendered = function () {
  this.data.quill = new Quill(...);
}
```

```html
<template name="editor">...</template>
```

Inside `form`'s `created` callback, create an `Editor` and store it on the template instance. Then when you call out to the `editor` template, pass in the `Editor` instance as the data context.

```js
Template.form.created = function () {
  this.editor = new Editor();
}

Template.form.helpers({
  editorInstance: function () {
    return Template.instance().editor;
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="form">
  <form>
    {{> editor editorInstance }}
    <input type="submit" value="save"/>
  </form>
</template>
```

You can then define methods on the `Editor` prototype which can be called by the `form`:

```js
Editor.prototype.getTextAsHTML = function () {
  return this.quill && this.quill.getHTML();
}

Template.form.events({
  "submit form": function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var html = tmpl.editor.getTextAsHTML();
    // ...
  }
}
```

This is a nice way to abstract the details of the `editor` so that the `form` doesn't need to know about it. You can reuse the `editor` and if you ever want to change it, you just have to make sure `getTextAsHTML` works the same.

Comment: Hey @userXXX, any chance you'd get a [more meaningful username](http://www.linklink.io/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.archive.org%2Fweb%2F20140709094611%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fmsmvps.com%2Fblogs%2Fjon_skeet%2Farchive%2F2010%2F08%2F29%2Fwriting-the-perfect-question.aspx&path=%2Fhtml%2Fbody%2Fdiv%5B4%5D%2Fform%2Fdiv%5B3%5D%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%5B2%5D%2Fdiv%5B2%5D%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%2Ful%5B4%5D%2Fli)?

Comment: awesome, got my issue working with this technique, thank you!

Comment: Looking back over this code, this opened my eyes a little to how the templating works in Meteor.  Thanks again for sharing this.