# QuillJS with Meteor - How to insert content to db?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, quill

I am learning by doing some meteorJS and came across QuillJS as a text editor. Right now I have troubles understanding the connections between the function and the way to insert the written content to my Blog-Collection.

This is how I tried to access the content of the quill editor:

```
Template.blogform.events({
  'submit #blogForm': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $('#blogTitle').val();
    var body = document.querySelector('input[name=blogBody]');
    about.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents());

    Meteor.call('submitPost', title, body);
  }
});
```

But with the `onRendered` around the quill variable, the console throws me an error: *"quill Invalid Quill container #editor"*.
This is my initialization of the quilljs, which I load as a node package:

```
Template.blogform.onRendered(function () {
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: {
      toolbar: true
    },
    theme: "snow"
  });
});
```

**Q1:** How can I insert the content of my quill editor to a collection?

**Q2:** Is it the best practice, to have the blogform.events together with the quill = new Quill in the same file or should I split this to a editor.js and a blogform.js?

Thank you!

Comment: I finally found the solution in Camillos answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549964/how-to-access-nested-template-attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The error "quill Invalid Quill container #editor" means that Quill can't find an element with #editor id when you are calling "new Quill('#editor', {})".

Make sure that the element you pass to Quill exists before creating the editor.

I suggest asking Q2 separately and as a meteor question because it isn't specifically related to Quill.

Comment: I think my problem is that I can not access the 'quill' variable which is defined in the `Template.onRendered` to call it inside the `Template.events`. Everything works as I need it if I put the quill declaration inside the `Template.onRendered`

Got any help for me here how to access the declared variable?

Comment: I can't help you with Meteor but I can suggest to change the question so it only contain Meteor code that reproduce your issue without using Quill. Try to define a simple variable in Template.onRendered and call it inside Template.events. You'll probably have the same problem but now someone familiar with Meteor will be able to help you.